# Format-control for abbreviating long strings

Tags: format, common-lisp

Is there a way to construct format-control that will leave strings of certain small lengths as they are and shorten longer strings as:

```
(defparameter *control*) ;; put proper value here
(defparameter *str* "Lorem ipsum dolor")
(format nil "~@?" *control* *str*) ;; -> "Lorem ipsum dolor"
(defparameter *str* "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
(format nil "~@?" *control* *str*) ;; -> "Lorem ipsum...g elit"
```

Comment: You should look into the `~/name/` directive. It allows you to call an arbitrary function `name` within a format control.

Comment: At that point calling format is not needed, though

Comment: Only if you want to embed this into more formatting.

Comment: There's the library `(str:shorten <length> <string>)` which cuts the end if needed and adds an ellipsis.